# Why does compiler treat class as abstract?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I tried to compile the program, but compiler treats `ParameterExpr` class as abstract. I did not work with multiple inheritance and I thought that it should be work (because `get_type` was actually implemented in `Expr` class)

```
class IMetaExpression
{
public:
    virtual int get_type(void) = 0;
    virtual ~IMetaExpression(){}
};

class IParameterExpression : public IMetaExpression
{
public:
    virtual char get_parameter(void) = 0;
};
class Expr : public IMetaExpression
{
public:
    virtual int get_type(void) override { return 0; }
};
class ParameterExpr : public Expr, public IParameterExpression
{
public:
    virtual char get_parameter(void) override { return 'c';}
    //virtual int get_type(void) override { return 0; }
};
int main()
{
    auto p = new ParameterExpr();
    p->get_type();
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int get_type()` and`char get_parameter()` are not the same type

Comment: `ParameterExpr` inherits from `IParameterExpression` which has a pure virtual member function `get_type` that itself had inherited from `IMetaExpression`.  Since `ParameterExpr` does not implement that pure virtual member function, it makes that class *abstract*.  It's missing `get_type` is unrelated to `Expr::get_type`.

Comment: @Eljay but base class of ParameterExpr actually implements method `get_type`. That's why in my opinion ParameterExpre automatically implements `get__type`

Comment: That's a different `get_type`.  If you want it to be the same `get_type` you need to use *virtual inheritance*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is an issue called the diamond problem.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-inheritance-in-c/

This is where two classes inherit fully or partially from a base class, which then also has a child class inheriting both of these classes. Creating a diamond shape.

The solution to this is adding `virtual` to the inheritance of the two middle classes. Resulting in:

```
class IParameterExpression : virtual public IMetaExpression
```

and

```
class Expr : virtual public IMetaExpression
```

This allows the constructor of the base class to be called only once and sharing functionality between all inherited classes.

I am not an expert on the diamond problem, so more clarification is appreciated.